# System doesn't respond

Tags: 11.10

I am using `Ubuntu 11.10`. My computer configuration is `Core 2 Duo` processor,`1 GB RAM`,`500 GB` HDD. Normally it works fine but when I open firefox or watch movies  or copying a large file, all my system hangs for 1-2 minutes. After that the system doesn't respond as smooth as it was before hanging. All I need to restart the system. Is this some kind of hardware problem or there need to configure something in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Run the system monitor and see the process.Find out which application uses most of RAM.Try to kill the application which uses most of the RAM (or close it first and use the other as your RAM is only 1GB) if it was opened by yourself(important:dont try to kill system process as it might kill all your system).